# Java Streams - How to preserve the initial Order of elements while using Collector groupingBy()

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to convert a *list* of objects into a *list of lists* of objects, i.e. `List<T>` into `List<List<T>>` and group them by a *list of strings* used as sorting *keys*.

The problem is that after the `groupingBy()`, the return value is a map, and that map a different order of values.

What can I do to preserve the initial order of elements in the list `groupedTreesList`?

*My code:*

```
Map<List<String>,List<QueryTreeProxy>> groupedMap = treesProxyList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        QueryTreeProxy::getMappingKeys,
        Collectors.toList()
    ));

List<List<QueryTreeProxy>> groupedTreesList = groupedMap.values().stream().toList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `groupingBy()`, the return value is a map and that map output a different order of values list

You can use another flavor of [`groupingBy(classifier, mapFactory, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)), which allows you to specify the type of the Map. And we can use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the initial order.

And there's no need to generate the second stream, you can use parameterized contractor of `ArrayList` instead.

```
Map<List<String>, List<QueryTreeProxy>> groupedMap = treesProxyList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        QueryTreeProxy::getMappingKeys,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.toList()
    ));
    
List<List<QueryTreeProxy>> groupedTreesList = new ArrayList<>(groupedMap.values());
```

Besides that, using a mutable object as a key isn't a good practice.